# Selecting the last child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how I'd get an alert of a last child by clicking a link.

```
    <h3 id="comment:5" class="myclass">
```

This is how far I got:

```
$('#lastcomment').click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

My aim is to jump to the last comment by clicking the link. An alert would be fine for the first step I guess. So that I can see the last child of the comments.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to alert?

Comment: TI want to alert the last comment. In this case comment:9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector or [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) method:

```
$("#lastcomment").click(function () { 
    var lastComment = $("h3[id^=comment]:last");

    alert(lastComment.attr("id"));
}
```

Comment: Pretty much the answer I was looking for.

Comment: You don't know a name of a function that instead of alerting jumps to the comment?

Comment: @Faili: you should be able to use `window.location.hash = lastComment.attr("id");`

Comment: Thank you so much. Hash was it. Learning by asking :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery's `:last` selector. but i need to see more HTML to make something work...

Answer (score 0):

So you have a link that you want to go to the last comment on a page? Why not give the comment an id of comment-12 (for example), then just change your anchor to relfect this:

```
<a class="myclass" href="#comment-12" id="last-comment"> </a>
```

If you are wanting to do this in javascript, something like:

```
$('#lastcomment').click(function() {
  var numComments = $(".comments").length; // Assuming your comments have a class
  window.location = window.location.href + "#" + $(".comments").eq(numComments).attr("id");
});
```