# Selecting the last child elements of a div without looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a quick one. I'm trying to get better at writing selectors for jquery because I seem to be relying on loops far too much in order to get things done.

In this particular example, I want to add the "Absolute" class too all of the divs that have the ganttview-block-container class except the last one in the parent ganntview-blocks div.

HTML:

```
<div class='ganttview-blocks'>    
 <div class='ganttview-block-container'></div>
 <div class='ganttview-block-container'></div>
 <div class='ganttview-block-container'></div>    
</div>

<div class='ganttview-blocks'>    
 <div class='ganttview-block-container'></div>
 <div class='ganttview-block-container'></div>
 <div class='ganttview-block-container'></div> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("div.ganttview-block-container").addClass("Absolute").addClass("Opacity");

$($("div.ganttview-blocks")).each(function () {
  var thisDiv = $(this);
  thisDiv.children("div.ganttview-block-container:last").removeClass("Absolute");    
});
```

My javascript/jquery accomplishes this goal correctly but it seems so inefficient. I'm confident there's a more elegant way of getting this done... perhaps even in 1 line.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543513/getting-last-child-of-div

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768641/selecting-the-last-child

Comment: I took a look at those questions before posting but they didn't address what I was looking for specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector) with [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector):

```
$('.ganttview-block-container')
  .addClass('Opacity')
  .filter(':not(:last-child)')
    .addClass('Absolute');
```

Comment: Awesome! This is the type of stuff I was looking for. I've got to get more comfortable using :not and learn more about the other ':' options.

Comment: @Robodude Have a look through [the API reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for starters.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Will do!

Answer (score 0):

why not just do

```
$("div.ganttview-blocks div.ganttview-block-container:last").each( ... )
```

That *should* get you the elements your after.